# How to play video from laravel storage directory after verifying the User Login

Tags: php, laravel

i have been developing a service where users will be able to access content only and only if they have paid for the content . so i am uploading the content to storage directory and for accessing content i have created routes like this ..

```
Route::any('storage/course/videos/{video_id}',['uses'=>'StorageController@video','middleware'=>'auth']);
```

and then in storage controller i am fetching file and returning it as response like this ...

```
public function video($video_id){
    //Some logic for subscription check goes here
        $path = storage_path('app/public/course/videos/'.$video_id);
        // return $path;
        if (!File::exists($path)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $file = File::get($path);
        $type = File::mimeType($path);

        $response = Response::make($file, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
        // $response->header("Accept-Ranges", 'bytes');
         //$response->header("Content-Length", 51265590);
         // $response->header("Content-Disposition" ,"attachment");  //Triggers Download

        return $response;
    }
```

This trick is working as expected for images but not for videos .Even video download is working but browser fails to play the video each time .Initially i thought there might be some header missing but so i tried to some headers but it didn't work.

So does anyone what i am doing wrong OR is it even possible to do so OR any other technique to achieve this

Thanks In Advance !!

Comment: You really don't want to be doing `file_get_contents` on a giant video file. It loads the entire thing into memory. I'd be looking at Amazon S3 or something similar; it has the ability to keep a file private, but to create expiring "signed URLs" that are only valid for a configurable period of time. See "temporary URLs" at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-urls.

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry the file_get_contents was not part of it . i was just trying this method but later discovered the same issue of loading entire video  at once

Comment: `Response::make` does the same thing here. You should look at `Response::streamDownload` (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#file-downloads).

Comment: @ceejayoz streamDownload didn't work but thanks for trying .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after using an additional VideoStream Class that i got from here https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/d5682ad426525196d069

```
 public function video($video_id){

        $path = storage_path('app/public/course/videos/'.$video_id);

        if (!File::exists($path)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $stream = new \App\Http\VideoStream($path);

        return response()->stream(function() use ($stream) {
            $stream->start();
        });
    }
```